Пропала кирилица после билда в WebGL
В Unity все отображает нормально, но после билда в WebGL пропадает вся кирилица, остаються только запятые или числа с английскими буквами. Шриф использовал стандартный ничего не менял. В чем может быть проблема? 

Проблема с отображением кириллицы в Unity WebGL обычно связана с настройками шрифта. По умолчанию Unity оптимизирует шрифты, оставляя только те символы, которые используются в проекте на момент билда. Если кириллица не была явно указана, она может быть исключена.
Попробуй изменить настройку шрифта на "Dynamic" или добавь нужные символы вручную:

Выбери свой шрифт в проекте.

В инспекторе найди параметр Character (или Characters).
Установи:

Dynamic — если шрифт поддерживает динамическую загрузку
всех символов.
Unicode — для полной загрузки символов Unicode.
Custom Set — если хочешь вручную указать используемые символы
(кириллицу).


В поле Custom Set введи диапазон символов, например:


АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя
